# Smart way to create a date functionality?

Tags: php, mysql, date, datepicker

Current MySQL table schema: "Date" column with yyyy-mm-dd values

Assuming you are building a web app to rent out XBox's.  Would you:

1. Create a a few checkboxes with "Every Monday," "Every Tuesday," "etc..." (Implication: If it's every Monday, how would you insert dates of only Monday's into the DB? Perhaps only insert the Monday's for the next three months initially and auto-increment and keep the tables light?"
2. Use a multi-datepicker for users to select multiple dates (Implication: User experience drops since the user will need to select more dates as time progresses?)
3. Other options?

How would add "hours" in addition to dates?

Answer (score 0):

Store the data separately:

- Start date - the start of the range
- End date - the end of the range
- Days of the week - the days of the week during the range (store this as a JSON array)
- Hours per day - the hours per day (store this as a JSON object, with either start/end time per day of the week)

Answer (score 0):

Try taking a look at Google Calendar add event page.  They organize the times very smartly.  It should give you some ideas for it.